# IO::Pipe - close(<handle>) does not set $?

Tags: perl

My understanding is that closing the handle for an `IO::Pipe` object should be done with the method (`$fh->close`) and not the built-in (`close($fh)`).

The other day I goofed and used the built-in out of habit on a `IO::Pipe` object that was opened to a command that I expected to fail. I was surprised when `$?` was zero, and my error checking wasn't triggered.

I realized my mistake. If I use the built-in, `IO:Pipe` can't perform the `waitpid()` and can't set `$?`. But what I was surprised by was that perl seemed to still close the pipe without setting `$?` via the core.

I worked up a little test script to show what I mean:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

use IO::Pipe;

say 'init pipes:';
pipes();
my $fh = IO::Pipe->reader(q(false));
say 'post open pipes:';
pipes();

say 'return: ' . $fh->close;
#say 'return: ' . close($fh);
say 'status: ' . $?;
say q();

say 'post close pipes:';
pipes();

sub pipes
   {
   for my $fd ( glob("/proc/self/fd/*") )
      {
      say readlink($fd) if -p $fd;
      }
   say q();
   }
```

When using the method it shows the pipe being gone after the close and `$?` is set as I expected:

```
init pipes:

post open pipes:
pipe:[992006]

return: 1
status: 256

post close pipes:
```

And, when using the built-in it also appears to close the pipe, but does not set `$?`:

```
init pipes:

post open pipes:
pipe:[952618]

return: 1
status: 0

post close pipes:
```

It seems odd to me that the built-in results in the pipe closure, but doesn't set `$?`. Can anyone help explain the discrepancy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code for `IO::Handle` (of which `IO::Pipe::End` is a sub-class), you will see the following:

```
sub close {
    @_ == 1 or croak 'usage: $io->close()';
    my($io) = @_;

    close($io);
}
```

It looks like `$fh->close` just calls `close $fh`. Of course, we should not be peeking behind the curtain.

We can see after `IO::Pipe` does a `close $fh` (behind the scenes), it then does a waitpid:

```
package IO::Pipe::End;

our(@ISA);

@ISA = qw(IO::Handle);

sub close {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $r = $fh->SUPER::close(@_);   # <-- This just calls a CORE::close

    waitpid(${*$fh}{'io_pipe_pid'},0)
        if(defined ${*$fh}{'io_pipe_pid'});

    $r;
}
```

Also  interesting is this from the close Perldoc:

> If the filehandle came from a piped open, close returns false if one of the other syscalls involved fails or if its program exits with non-zero status. If the only problem was that the program exited non-zero, $! will be set to 0 .
>
> **Closing a pipe also waits for the process executing on the pipe to exit** --in case you wish to look at the output of the pipe
>
> afterwards--and implicitly **puts the exit status value of that command
>   into $? and ${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE} .**

That answers your question right there.

Answer (score 1):

> But what I was surprised by was that perl seemed to still close the pipe without setting $? via the core.

Why would it? It has no way to know the process at the other end is a child, much less one for which the program should wait. Since it has no reason to call `waitpid`, `$?` isn't going to get set.

In fact, I doubt it wait for the process at the other end of the pipe even if it wanted to, because I doubt there's a way of obtaining the pid of the process at the other end of the pipe, because it's actually possible for there to be multiple processes at the other end of the pipe.

`IO::Pipe::close` only calls `waitpid` when IO::Pipe is used to "open a process".

Similarly, `close` only calls `waitpid` when `open` is used to "open a process".

A process "opened" using one method cannot be closed by the other.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my confusion stems from a flawed assumption that the disappearing pipe coincided with a complete process termination. That appears to not be the case, as the process is still available for a `wait()`.

```
> perl -MIO::Pipe -le 'my $io = IO::Pipe->reader(q(false)); close($io); print $?; print wait(); print $?'
0
8857
256
```